ImageMagick for Linux Alma 8 success but which no magick
I am trying to publish pages or posts in WordPress 6.5.5 (Linux Alma 8)
the message in wordpress is:
The publication has failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.
On error_log:
[root@host]# dnf install ImageMagick
Last metadata expiration check: 1:12:03 ago on Wed 17 Jul 2024 03:07:58 AM -04.
Package ImageMagick-6.9.12.93-1.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

AND..
[root@host]# which magick
/usr/bin/which: no magick in (/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/root/bin)

the RESULT for: rpm -ql ImageMagick-6.9.12.93-1.el8.x86_64
/usr/bin/animate
/usr/bin/compare
/usr/bin/composite
/usr/bin/conjure
/usr/bin/convert
/usr/bin/display
/usr/bin/identify
/usr/bin/import
/usr/bin/mogrify
/usr/bin/montage
/usr/bin/stream
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/1b
/usr/lib/.build-id/1b/61cc44f32e47fdaf8819023321505fc7c52f90
/usr/lib/.build-id/21
/usr/lib/.build-id/21/cf3b83ca81dd9b250b61ccb8cf6503d3fc0568
/usr/lib/.build-id/2a
/usr/lib/.build-id/2a/2347455cc60dd405cf9a7e9fcc57d1796a8ee5
/usr/lib/.build-id/37
/usr/lib/.build-id/37/0b34e7ffa9074e31ad80c2046e24a98665fd1e
/usr/lib/.build-id/48
/usr/lib/.build-id/48/1a7bf01ba64a7fbc647a800a0c24b56d6dc5b1
/usr/lib/.build-id/60
/usr/lib/.build-id/60/81c7fd53c88aa0e05cc164ce0666f0f938fb0d
/usr/lib/.build-id/80
/usr/lib/.build-id/80/b1ccae696bc3802a2d1b88c9f7864d4af820a0
/usr/lib/.build-id/a1
/usr/lib/.build-id/a1/c1c42c305c60773a504a56338f7df0f3cfb42b
/usr/lib/.build-id/d9
/usr/lib/.build-id/d9/cd8858acbbba76bb6af714426377ca5c004477
/usr/lib/.build-id/eb
/usr/lib/.build-id/eb/1152eff94403e205d2e057d591924834ca7908
/usr/lib/.build-id/f3
/usr/lib/.build-id/f3/80eaa15d7a7ec13e4af4324d25ec850287678c
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick/AUTHORS.txt
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick/NEWS.txt
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick/NOTICE
/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick/README.txt
/usr/share/man/man1/ImageMagick.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/animate.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/compare.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/composite.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/conjure.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/convert.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/display.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/identify.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/import.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mogrify.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/montage.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/stream.1.gz

What is the result of rpm -ql ImageMagick-6.9.12.93-1.el8.x86_64

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is a wonderful place wordpress

add the output of rpm -ql in the main question, thanks for the feedback

I solved it adding a configuration on the htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

